# Android - Skipping frames when trying to login to server from application. (async)

Tags: android, asynchronous

```
   public class AppApi extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private OkHttpClient client;
    private Request request;
    private MediaType JSON;
    private String URL;
    private RequestBody body;

    public AppApi(JSONObject obj) {
        client = new OkHttpClient();
        JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        URL = "http://serverapi.domain.com/user/login";
        Log.d("Information",obj.toString());
        body = RequestBody.create(JSON, obj.toString());
        request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .post(body)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        // execute fonksiyonu cagrilarak calistirilir
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("doInBackground()", ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        // showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
    }
}

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        login();
    }
}
```

LoginActivity.Java below.

```
private void login() {
    JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    try {
        data.put("email", "email");
        data.put("password", "pass");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }

    AppApi api = new AppApi(data);

    try {
        String result = api.execute().get();
        Log.d("login()", result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So the problem with the application is that we can't properly login to our https server. Android Studio says it is skipping frames.

> I/Choreographer: Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too
>   much work on its main thread.

When we try to enter the wrong password intentionally, it skips even more frames.(200ish)
I think we did most of the coding correctly on the Async task side. How can we check the return value? How can we solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the build request into the background thread as well .i.e

```
private JSONObject obj;
public AppApi(JSONObject obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        // execute fonksiyonu cagrilarak calistirilir
        try {
client = new OkHttpClient();
        JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        URL = "http://serverapi.domain.com/user/login";
        Log.d("Information",obj.toString());
        body = RequestBody.create(JSON, obj.toString());
        request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .post(body)
                .build();
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            return response.body().string();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("doInBackground()", ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Now I can get a response from the server but frame skipping issue continues.

Comment: Try to remove all your calls to Log